# Insert tables into Oracle through jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, insert

I've never done anything with JDBC or much with Oracle, but I've connected to my jdbc this way:

```
     String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
         Class.forName(driverName);

         // Create a connection to the database
         String serverName = "xxx.xx.xx;
         String portNumber = "1521";
         String sid = "mysid";
         String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber  
                                               + ":" + sid;
         String username = "PGSWLOG";
         String password = "PGDEV";
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Now what classes do i need to use to insert tables into the database? Any help would be appreciates. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote `insert tables into the database`, did you mean

1) Create a new table in DB, or

2) Add new row(s) into an existing DB table?

In either case, read the [tutorials posted by @Marcelo Hernández Ris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035688/insert-tables-into-oracle-through-jdbc/6035878#6035878) and then follow with the good examples for [JDBC and Sql92](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CatalogDatabase-SQL-JDBC.htm) syntax on http://www.java2s.com/.

Comment: I just need to insert rows. The tables are already there. My wording was way off. Sorry

Comment: ok :-)   1) Oracle tutorial 2) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CatalogDatabase-SQL-JDBC.htm 3) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/CatalogOracle.htm   much luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need the PreparedStatement class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

And from the Java Tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html